# jQuery selector id like with exactly one wildcard character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

> **Summary**

I have to delete blank entries before they get submitted to the server.

The elements to be selected are HTML tables with an Id. They have all the same Id pattern.

**Id Pattern**: `couvertureAdditionnelle_%`

**%**: it's a given index based on the number of tables with such an Id on the page.

So for instance:

```
<table id="couvertureAdditionnelle_0">        
    ...
    <table id="couvertureAdditionnelle_0_descriptions">
        ...
    </table>
    ...
</table>
<table id="couvertureAdditionnelle_1">
    ...
    <table id="couvertureAdditionnelle_1_descriptions">
        ...
    </table>
    ...
</table>
...
<table id="couvertureAdditionnelle_13">
    ...
    <table id="couvertureAdditionnelle_13_descriptions">
        ...
    </table>
    ...
</table>
...
```

So, I already have a javascript function to delete a single row for which the given table id is assigned directly whilst it's generated by the server.

I now want to get these tables and check on the client whether they are empty. If they are, then I need to delete them so that they don't get submitted to the server.

> **Current situation**

As of now, I am almost there, only missing a little touch to get it working.

```
var couverturesAdditionnelles = $("table[id^=couvertureAdditionnelle_");
```

I got all the tables I want, plus those I don't. Yes, because I also get tables named like `couvertureAdditionnelle_0_descriptions`.

> **Question**

Basically, I want to select only the tables named like:

```
`couvertureAdditionnelle_0`
```

How can I select only those?

Or how can I avoid to select the tables named like `couvertureAdditionnelle_0_descriptions`?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you place common classes on the parent/child tables, then use the `:empty` selector to remove the relevant ones. Incremental `id` attributes are an anti-pattern which leads to needlessly complex code - as you've now discovered.

Comment: If it's just `table_0` and `table_0_descriptions` then exclude the descriptions with `:not([id$=_descriptions)`: `$("table[id^=couvertureAdditionnelle_").not("table[id$=_descriptions]")`

Comment: the [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector should help you do that

Comment: Can you add a class to the outer tables?  `<table id="couvertureAdditionnelle_0" class='outertable'>`  then it's just `$(".outertable")`  (I'm not entirely sure if this is the same as that which @RoryMcCrossan suggested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude certain members from the found elements with the `:not()` pseudo-class:

```
var couverturesAdditionnelles = 
  $("table[id^=couvertureAdditionnelle_]:not([id$=_descriptions]"));
```

Comment: I tried with the outertable class selector and for some reasons that are obscurs to me, that didn't work. So I went with your answer and it works flawlessly. THANK YOU!!!